# Computer peripherals to immediately (<5ms) detect digital input state change in C# programs

Tags: digital-logic, interrupts, software, hardware, input

The C# application I'm working on needs to be able to be able to call a function within 5 milliseconds of a digital input signal's state change (0V = off, 5V = on).

Rather than using software to repeatedly poll that input's state, I would like some hardware to simply call a software function when the hardware detects a state change (like how hardware interrupts work).

Does anyone know how to do this (what ports to use) on a standard PC tower? Or does anyone know of any hardware peripherals that allow this functionality?

Occasional latencies are fine. I need <5ms average.

I basically need to take as many samples as possible of the input digital waveform. (preferably in the C# program, rather than in a peripheral micro-controller, although I am open to suggestions).

For instance, I found out the Labjack U3 can poll its digital input in less than a millisecond. This is a valid answer to the question, but I am interesting in more answers, especially ones that don't use polling or poll faster than 1ms.

High input impedance would be nice (digital inputs).

Comment: 2ms hard realtime response? Under Windows?

Comment: No way you are doing it. If you tell us the *real* problem, we might help you to come up with appropriate solution.

Comment: I already verified I could do it using a LabJack U3 (a micro-controller device) and repeatedly polling its input state (which can be done every one millisecond.) So the question is not ludicrous. I want more ideas. For instance keyboard and mouse interrupts occur in nanoseconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: The ludicrous part is expecting a standard OS to give you this level of responsiveness. Standard OS's are designed to give you peak throughput, at the expense of latency. Even a modern multi-GHz system might have occasional latencies on the order of many microseconds or longer into milliseconds with a regular OS depending on what's running. There are special OS's designed for real-time problems (including a special version of Windows). Micro-controllers often either don't have an OS or use one of these real-time OS's to give you near-zero latency.

Comment: @OrangeSherbet Interrupts may occur in zero time, but their handling in OS is much slower.

Comment: Anyway, you might be able to achieve this latency sometimes. But you can't rely on it, as it is not guaranteed.

Comment: The application does not require steady latency. It is an algorithm designed to learn data about the input's repeating waveform, and the algorithm's performance is fundamentally limited by how often I can learn about the input. I basically want to take as many samples as possible, it does not matter if the samples are staggered and unsteady.

Comment: Anyway, as you are saying you are familiar with some MCU stuff, I would suggest implementing the sampling on the MCU side, packing the data in some way and sending it over some communication channel to the computer.

Comment: Like a DAQ? I will have to abandon some code but I believe you are probably right Eugene.

Comment: Something like this. Just make sure you will be able to achieve the rate you want taking in account the rate the communication frames will be processed

Comment: Neither the mouse nor keyboard response rates are anywhere even close to nanoseconds. A USB full speed interrupt response is 1ms and even on a a 2.0 high speed device the best you can can do is 125us.

Comment: USB packet latency is probably hundreds of times larger than signal-to-Interrupt time.

Comment: What is the minimum time between two pulses?

Comment: 50 milliseconds (almost said microseconds) for a full period (about 50% duty cycle) is the minimum. Ideally I could figure out when the signal goes high within a short amount of time. In other words it could be about 20 milliseconds high, followed by about 20 milliseconds low, etc, so hopefully in 20ms I can get several samples done.

Comment: sounds like you need a microcontroller to do the sampling, and then serial packet (usb or classical serial) to a user-space program to do batch processing  in between each event. This is definitely achievable. Get something cheap and easy like a Teensy 3.1 for $20

Comment: I had a Atmega328P doing serious data sampling and byte-packed message spamming to a C# application using a USB-Serial converter in Windows 7, and also on Linux in a robot using C++, and it worked beautifully in both cases, for very time sensitive applications (encoder of motor, for detecting the angle).

Comment: @KyranF you did a wrong thing; garbage collected languages are unfit for " very time sensitive applications". The delays can be arbitrarily long.

Comment: @ilkhd did you not read what I did? I used a microcontroller for the data collection, and send the data in bursts with timestamps up to the computer for processing/storage/association with LIDAR data

Comment: @ilkhd the C# or C++ program trying to do the data sampling and timestamping would have failed horribly at the task, as you say - but it has nothing to do with garbage collection. It's the operating system and the random 10ms delays come OS (kernel) level operations which ruin the performance

Comment: @KyranF Do you understand how garbage collector works? C# is unfit for anything which requires less than 1 minute random delays.

Comment: @ilkhd you must be doing something wrong mate, sorry.

Comment: @KyranF if I need even very relaxed real-time I would not do it with a garbage collected language; c or c++ are fine but not C#, "mate".

Comment: @ilkhd My experience proves otherwise, you overestimate the delays. It may not be guaranteed performance but 1 minute random delays? No. I had amazing speed, zero delays, AND all running in a Windows Forms GUI application to boot.

Comment: @KyranF Thank you for your constructive suggestions. The Teensy 3.1 looks like it would work great, except I am having trouble finding a .NET library for C# for the Teensy. I guess in general a small arduino with .NET functionality would be nice. But Labjack is even simpler, although 108$...

Comment: Check out the .NETduino. But why do you want a C# library for the Teensy? You program it with Arduino using TeensyDuino plug-in for the Arduino IDE, and you define a simple serial interface between the Teensy and a C# program, where the C# program is just receiving and processing serial packets.

Comment: I'm kind of lost on what you mean "define a simple serial interface and a c# program", how do I define such a thing? Is there some kind of usb(?) communication library to communicate with the Teensy during a C# program? Maybe System.IO.Ports?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to perform a specific real-time action, or just record the event?

If the former, you will never accomplish this using commodity hardware and consumer-grade interfaces. You will need both a laboratory-grade signal processor ( it will be a card that can access hardware interrupts directly) and a real-time operating system like VxWorks. A user-centric OS won't interrupt a disk write just because the USB bus wants some attention.

If the latter, get yourself a signal recorder and post-process the buffer output at your convenience.

Comment: I do not need to do anything in real-time, I simply need to time-stamp and record falling and rising edges, as they occur. I'm not sure what you mean by "signal recorder", but I really don't want do put the digital line into any ADCs, analog functionality is not really what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If your signal does not have too much of DC (long pauses with no data), use the sound card.

Comment: Explain why....

Comment: @Null what exactly you want me to explain?

Comment: My signal has long periods of low DC (10 seconds of low). A sound card is an innovative idea, however I would have to scale my digital input down to 400mV, and I don't really need all the analog capability, would be better to go directly to something with a Digital Input pin.

Comment: @OrangeSherbet well, a standard modern PC does not have a buffered digital input. Sound card is the only option. to limit the digital signal all you need is a diode and 3 resistors. If you decide to go the sound card way, I'll explain how to deal with DC.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an Arduino Uno's `Timer Input Capture Interrupt Service Routine` to set data over USB to a C# `SerialPort` object immediately upon input capture. The `SerialPort` fires a `serialdatareceivedeventhandler` immediately upon detecting an End Of File Character (0x1A), and a new thread launches to process the input data (such as assigning a timestamp to it).

To all the neighsayers, What the Heck? Obviously you were wrong that it couldn't be done.

Comment: Have you *verified* your max 5ms latency??

Comment: I'm not sure how I would measure that (how to synchronize arduino and computer...), but it appears that I have a resolution of about 2 milliseconds (not latency, instead that's how much the latency varies). I really needed a latency that didn't vary by more than a few milliseconds, a constant latency was desirable.